# How to access the Google Places API in Android?

Tags: android

I am working on an application which uses google places API.

I got API key for my application,but the problem is I am getting `ZERO_RESULTS` as a response from the sever.

Here is my code I used `DefaultHttpClient` to establish the http connection. Can anyone tell me what is the problem?
Please help I am stuck here.

```
public class Splash extends Activity{
     private  String keystring="";
     //This is my request url 
    String requesturl="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?" + 
      "location=17.739290150000002,83.3071201&radius=6000&" +
      "types=hospital&sensor=false&key=";
     private static byte[] key; 
     String signaturegot;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          /*
            Here I am using default http client to establish 
            the connection for the request url
           */
           
            HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
            StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder(requesturl);
            builder.append(URLEncoder.encode(keystring));
            HttpPost post=new HttpPost(requesturl);
            try {
                HttpResponse response=client.execute(post);
                HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                    String val = StaticUtils.convertStreamToString(is);
                Log.e("",val);
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {   
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }



Here is the response from the server
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Comment: Hiii all I solved my issue,i gave name instead of types in the request url.It worked for me.Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to some weird reason, for locations in India, instead of using `types` use `names`

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?&location=17.739290150000002,83.3071201&radius=6000&names=hospital&sensor=true&key=yourkeyhere

For the phone number, you have to request details using the reference string that you got from the above URL :

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?&reference=usethereferencestringfromtheaboveurl&sensor=true&key=yourkeyhere

The output will contain:

```
"formatted_phone_number" : "0891 123 0101",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 17.7060120,
            "lng" : 83.3104410
         }
      },
```

Comment: Hii Reno thanks for your post,I did the same thing what u have said.But here I need to get phone numbers too.How can i do that.could plz help me.Thanks

Comment: If you parse the Place Details Responses
 JSON structure, the phone number can be retrieved from `formatted_phone_number`

Comment: Reno Thank u for your reply.I did JSON parsing from the result which I got.I am unable to get the phone number from this.Could u explain u r point more clearly,should I send any new request for phone numbers.Did I correctly form the request url for getting phone numbers. Thanks